# BIRT Report took too long to render

Tags: sql-server, performance, birt

Write now multiple BIRT Reports using 4.9.0 version. Some reports working fast enough. But some reports are surprisingly very slow.
One report is extremely slow. Report is based on stored procedure, have 2 parameters. Contains two label with formatted text and one table with title and detail row. All data are prepared in correct form in DB. The only thing what BIRT should do is put data in detail rows and make some highlighting. Each row contains 15 columns. Only 4 data fields have number formatting other fields are unformatted.
DB request in SSMS took about 60ms for 12 rows. BIRT viewer tooks 6 seconds in browser. Full request with productive data took about 600ms for 75 rows. BIRT viewer tooks 650 seconds in browser.

I've tried remove highlighting - without change. Tried to give BIRT 4GB memory - no change. Have tried to profile BIRT using VisualVM: [image: Looks like it's used all the time for communication with DB]
Tried newest BIRT 4.12.0, newest sqlserver JDBC 12.2.0 everything without change.
Have no idea what todo else or how to test.

Comment: This is stored procedure execution time.  You can ignore the client, except to capture the _exact_ call with profiler to reproduce and troubleshoot in SQL Server.  Read: https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: Unbelievable! I've rewrite the query so, that is possible to put it directly into the report to see the possible impact. And the total time up to browser is drastically reduced from 659 to 1.1 seconds!!! Thank you for the hint. Next week I'll read entire article and try to analyse what going wrong with SP. Other reports with SP working well.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to call the SP from DBeaver - 553s. Then I've recompiled this SP - EXEC sp_recompile and magic, DBeaver runs my SP under 800ms! Then I've tried old report with SP and it runs faster then report with standalone query.
I've early created 3 indexes for the tables which are used in this SP. Before index creation report was fast, after - very slow.
I believe the problem is in SP cache. Sometimes if I recreate or alter some view - dependent views deliver no data or throws an error. After recreate dependent view - it works again. I observed this behavior in different DBs SQL Server, Oracle.
Is seams the same thing happened to the SP.
Conclusion: if some code runs suddenly slowly or throws unexpected errors try to recompile view/SP.

Edited on 10.03.2023. The better way I've found ist to add "WITH RECOMPILE" option to that stored procedures. See here [Recompile a Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure).
EXEC sp_recompile doesn't work always. But "WITH RECOMPILE" option for stored procedure works repeatedly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).